# Please help define "public economic consensus" used by Vitalik Buterin

Tags: economics, terminology

In a recent paper titled, "Ethereum Platform Review: Opportunities and Challenges for Private and Consortium Blockchains" by Vitalik Buterin, he mentions the notion of **public economic consensus**.

Can anyone help explain the definition of this term / notion and how it differs from something like public goods and common resources within economics? Is it synonymous with the idea of Proof of Work / Proof of Stake or is it different?

The paragraph it comes from is here:

> The Ethereum platform was originally conceived in November 2013 with
>   the goal of creating a more generalized blockchain platform, combining
>   together the notion of public economic consensus via proof of work (or
>   eventually proof of stake) with the abstraction power of a stateful
>   Turing-complete virtual machine in order to allow application
>   developers to much more easily create applications that benefit from
>   the decentralization and security properties of blockchains, and
>   particularly avoid the need to create a new blockchain for each new
>   application.

I am just looking for a better understanding of this concept and any reference / source material you can point me towards.

Answer (score 2):

It is not synonym for PoW or PoS.

> public economic consensus via proof of work

The semantics of the word *via* are not an equality operator, but a cause effect relationship. Public economic consensus is possible because of PoW or PoS.

> public

The ethereum blockchain is out in the public and anyone can introspect the state of the blockchain in history and in the most recent block.

> economic

the *consensus* is reached by an economic balance of selfish actors, the miners, who provably (bitcoin proved it for years out in the wild) reach consensus every time. Proof of x is a big part of this economic model. Some oldschoolers say it is the *Byzantine General's problem*, but I never digged into that.

> consensus

What is the true state of a thing when a swarm of egalitarian actors (Etherem nodes) need to reach an agreement? Ethereum creates facts that will never change.
[Consensus in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science))

Comment: It could be that Vitalik meant *economic consensus* that is *public* instead of a *consensus* that is reached in *public* and with *economic* principles. Than the interpretation would be different. But I do not believe in this variation, because the statement is less related to the topic of the paper.